# Remove an image using CSS attributes

Tags: css

I have a set of identical images that I don't wish to display, I hope to do this with display:none;

How can I target a src image url with CSS attributes?

So far, I have:

```
[src="mypic_68.png"] {
 display:none;
}
```

Comment: any chance we use jquery ?

Comment: You might want `[src$="mypic_68.png"]` to allow for host or path prefix

Answer (score 3):

I think you have src like this: `src="images/mypic_68.png"` then your code won't work. You may use:

```
[src$="mypic_68.png"] { //$ to indicate ending with
 display:none;
}
```

Here, you can find [all attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: Use `$=` as *.png* is probably suffix.